# imon bash script can't see python package installed, user generated bash script can

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, shebang

I recently added python 3.9 to my ubuntu installation.
Can run python3.9 code using an installed package from bash, can also run python 3.9 using an installed module from a bash script using a shebang to load the python 3.9 environment, fairly standard stuff.

But when I try running an installed script from https://github.com/gitbls/imon, the installed package is not found.

initially I thought this was fixed by changing the imon bash script shebang to reference the new python.
ie

```
old 
#!/usr/bin/python3
new
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

also added these lines to the imon script to verify which version of python in environment
import sys
print("sys.version:", sys.version)
```

when I run the /usr/local/bin/imon package, it reports 'no module' error.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/imon --nosyslog --instance my_instance_name
sys.version: 3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imon", line 11, in <module>
    from icmplib import ping, multiping
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icmplib'
```

the thing that is really throwing me, is the output shows the imon script is accepting the shebang to load python 3.9, but will not find the module, despite my script using identical code able to load the module.

my test exercises  below to verify and demonstrate I have python3.9 installed and a bash script can load python3.9 and the icmplib module.

```
$ python3.9
Python 3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)
3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
>>> import icmplib
```

ie: the icmplib package has been installed and can be used when in the python shell.

I created a shell script and made it executable

```
vim test_script.sh

#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import sys
print (sys.version)
import icmplib
print("icmplib.__version__:", icmplib.__version__)

chmod u+x test_script.sh
```

output from this shows the script is running python3.9 and can access the installed module.

```
$ ./test_script.sh
3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
icmplib.__version__: 3.0.3
```

#EDIT START--------------------------------------------------------------

added tests as suggested by @furas in comments.

```
print("sys.path:", sys.path)
print("icmplib.__file__:", icmplib.__file__)
```

these above lines were added to both test_script.sh & /usr/local/bin/imon

the results below reveal the local test_script.sh accesses a directory not accessed by the imon script run by root.

```
'/home/m/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
```

oddly, both the script run locally and the script run under root access path

```
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
```

(I don't know why python3 instead of python3.9 is in sys.path, this seems odd to me)

taking another suggestion from @furas I tried pip installing the module as root

```
$ sudo python3.9 -m pip install icmplib
Collecting icmplib
  Using cached icmplib-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Installing collected packages: icmplib
Successfully installed icmplib-3.0.3
```

this looked helpful. unfortunately running the imon script as root still resulted in the Namerror.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/imon --nosyslog --instance imon-bmt1
sys.version: 3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
sys.path: ['/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imon", line 8, in <module>
    print("icmplib.__file__:", icmplib.__file__)
NameError: name 'icmplib' is not defined
```

I am now 18hrs awake and brain fading. :(

#EDIT END--------------------------------------------------------------

#EDIT: this below was before the edit above.

when I run test_script.sh as root, I can replicate the error experienced by imon.

```
$ ./test_script.sh
3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
icmplib.__version__: 3.0.3
sys.path: ['/home/m/f_projs/internet_monitor', 
'/usr/lib/python39.zip', 
'/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', 
'/home/m/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
icmplib.__file__: /home/m/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/icmplib/__init__.py


$ sudo /usr/local/bin/imon --nosyslog --instance imon-bmt1
sys.version: 3.9.14 (main, Sep  7 2022, 23:43:29)
[GCC 9.4.0]
sys.path: ['/usr/local/bin', 
'/usr/lib/python39.zip', 
'/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/imon", line 8, in <module>
    print("icmplib.__file__:", icmplib.__file__)
NameError: name 'icmplib' is not defined
```

my environment = ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.9.14

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ which python3.9
/usr/bin/python3.9

$ python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.14

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Comment: Is there a copy of python inside of `/usr/local/bin` as well?

Comment: maybe it changes list `sys.path` and it can't find folder with module `icmplib`. You can check `print(sys.path)` and `print(icmplib.__file__)`

Comment: I don't know if you install modules with `sudo` but without `sudo` only current user may have installed modules - but you run script with `sudo` so it search modules installed for `root`

Comment: added the print(sys.path) and print(icmplib.__file__) as suggested by @furas, also tried sudo pip install icmplib, see updated post - EDITED section

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking this as 'answered' because I've realised I broke my python3 and python3.9 install beyond repair while attempting to fix this issue.

now I have a completely different problem.

most of the original problem appears to be failing to use 'sudo pip install X' (or  'sudo python3.9 -m pip install x') when installing packages. I normally use virtual env for my local projects.

I was doing uninstall of python3.9 and cleanup with view to reinstalling python3.9.

```
sudo apt remove python3.9
#now check what packages remain to be removed manually.
dpkg --list | grep python3.9
#this showed a short list of packages to be cleaned up.
#nb: 'rc' = package has been removed, but configuration files remain

sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3.9-minimal
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3.9-venv
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3.9

sudo dpkg -P libpython3.9-minimal
sudo dpkg -P python3.9-minimal
sudo dpkg -P python3.9-venv

#then manually deleting the python3.9 directories previously listed by sys.path 
ie
sudo rm -rf  /usr/lib/python3.9
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages
```

my new problem is due to accidentally deleting a directory from sys-path which 'apt-get remove' and 'sudo dpkg -P' didn't cleanup.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

hindsight screams out this will destroy the python3 install. Bitter experience just now tells me it is near impossible to repair since the apt-get tools are dependent on a working python3 install.

I think the only way to fix this is copying  across a full directory of '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages' from a clean install.

new SO question for my new problem > ([how to repair python3 install on ubuntu after rm -rf /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916602/how-to-repair-python3-install-on-ubuntu-after-rm-rf-usr-lib-python3-dist-packa))

Hopefully this post will be useful and a warning to others in future.